# What is the value of $1^i $?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Calculate $1^i $ and find main value.

---

Here is what I did. I wrote

$$1^i=e^{i\log(1)} $$

then

$=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)} $, $k\in {\bf Z} $

$=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi} $, $k\in {\bf Z} $

Main Value:

$=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}} $

Comment: The second equality after "then..." does not make sense.

Comment: Use `k \in z` rather than `k \epsilon z`.  Also, use `\Bbb Z`, not `z`.

Comment: @Jack, and the first.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

remember that $1=e^{2k\pi i}$, so $1^i=e^{2k\pi i\cdot i}$

Answer (score 0):

You lost me here, twice, as neither of these mathematical expressions follow from the ones preceding them:

> then
>
> $=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)} $, $k\epsilon z $
>
> $=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi} $, $k\epsilon z $

---

From this line:

> $1^i=e^{ilog(1)} $

You should get:
$$ e^{i\operatorname{Log}(1)} = e^{i(\ln|1| + i\operatorname{Arg}(1))} = e^{i(0 + i0)} = e^0 = 1$$
Note that $\operatorname{Arg}(1) = 0$ because $1$ is a positive real number.  And by "main value" I'm assuming you mean the value where $k = 0$, hence $k$ is omitted in the above.

Comment: ok, understand I use this form because I have a similar example $i^i $

Comment: But what about $$1^i=(e^{42i\pi})^i=e^{-42\pi}\ne1\ ?$$

Comment: @ioivaaannn, yes, for $i^i$ you'll get $\operatorname{Arg}(i) = \pi/2$.  But different bases could lead to different values of $\text{Arg}$.

Comment: @Did, $e^{42i\pi}$ corresponds to following my procedure with a specific nonzero value of OP's $k$, and I explained in my answer why I used $k = 0$.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation does not make sense. All you need to do is following the definition carefully:

$$1^i=\exp(i\log(1))\tag{*}$$

where the complex logarithm is multi-valued:
$$
\log(1)=\ln (1)+i\arg (1)=2k\pi i,\quad k\in{\bf Z}.
$$
Going back to (*), one has
$$
1^i=e^{-2k\pi},\quad k\in{\bf Z}. 
$$

The [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value) of $1^i$ is then given by taking $k=0$.